# JQuery LocalStorage

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I am having some issues with JQuery and local storage. I have a div I want to display only once every 4hrs.

Currently, this is my code:

```
$(function() {

  var now = (new Date()).getTime();
  var lastTime = 0;
  var lastTimeStr = localStorage['lastTime'];
  if (lastTimeStr) lastTime = parseInt(lastTimeStr, 10);
  if (now - lastTime > 24*60*60*1000) {


  //START UP FADEOUT SCREEN
  $('#startup').delay(1500).fadeOut(2000);

  } 
  localStorage['lastTime'] = ""+now;​

});
```

However, the fadeout no longer works.

Can anyone help me out with this one? Do I need some kind of plugin for localStorage?

Thanks

Comment: That looks fine to me. `localStorage` is not supported in IE < 8 though. What do you mean by "no longer works"?

Comment: Well, maybe you run it once and now `now - lastTime > 24*60*60*1000` is false for the next 24 hours. You probably should put `localStorage['lastTime'] = ""+now;​` *inside* the `if` statement.

Comment: Hi James, 
prior to this I just had the line:  $('#startup').delay(1500).fadeOut(2000); which worked fine. After putting the rest around it, the fadeout animation no longer works - the #startup div stays put. I have tried the same with an alert and its fine. Just doesnt seem to like this animation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Felix was right. In my css I had forgotten to apply display:none to the #startup element and so it was covering the screen ('sticking') as the fadeOut function was not running anymore, being set to a 24hr interval.